# My render is looking funky in both Eevee and cycles

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

[image]

My render is looking a little funky, I haven't had this happen before so wondering if there's something in the settings to mess with.  This is in Eevee, but I've also had this happen in Cycles.

Comment: Are you sure that you've not left a light for render (that you've disabled for preview)?

Comment: it seams that you using sun with a lot of watts

Comment: I was originally using a point lighting then switched to sun. 

How might I know if I left a light for render that I disabled for preview?

Comment: Check the *Viewport Shading* options (https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGYl1.png). [X] *Scene Lights* and [X] *Scene World* should be checked to have the same lighting in the preview as used in the render.

Comment: That did it! Thanks